# Is it possible to merge 2 webm video streams into one stream (in picture)

Tags: webrtc, webm

Is it possible to record 2 webm videos (with `WebRTC`) and then merge them into one stream (picture in picture).

Example:

> recording A shows camera A (streams out)
>
> recording B shows camera B (streams out)

stream A shows one frame with A+B as merged stream (interview between two people)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is by using the [Media Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API).

First you have to create a `<canvas>` where you will draw the two `<video>` elements. When creating the MediaRecorder you will pass the canvas stream: `new MediaRecorder(canvas.captureStream())`.

In a timeout/interval you will draw the two videos in the canvas: `canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);`.