# WebRTC mix local and remote audio steams and record

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

So far i've found a way only to record either local or remote using `MediaRecorder` API but is it possible to mix and record both steams and get a blob?

Please note its audio steam only and i don't want to mix/record in server side.

I've a `RTCPeerConnection` as `pc`.

```
var local_stream = pc.getLocalStreams()[0];
var remote_stream = pc.getRemoteStreams()[0];
var audioChunks = [];
var rec = new MediaRecorder(local_stream);
rec.ondataavailable = e => {
    audioChunks.push(e.data);
    if (rec.state == "inactive") 
        // Play audio using new blob
}
rec.start();
```

Even i tried adding multiple tracks in `MediaStream` API but it still gives only first track audio. Any help or insight 'd be appreciated!

Comment: @AdrianBer, my question is different. Mix two audio streams and record it as a single steam object. So the you can hear both the party's conversation in a single audio element. And practically you can't mix two video streams and get one stream to view it.

Comment: I retracted my vote. You can actually mix two video streams, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966322/is-it-possible-to-merge-2-webm-video-streams-into-one-stream-in-picture

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [WebAudio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) can do mixing for you. Consider this code if you want to record all the audio tracks in the array `audioTracks`:

```js
const ac = new AudioContext();

// WebAudio MediaStream sources only use the first track.
const sources = audioTracks.map(t => ac.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([t])));

// The destination will output one track of mixed audio.
const dest = ac.createMediaStreamDestination();

// Mixing
sources.forEach(s => s.connect(dest));

// Record 10s of mixed audio as an example
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(dest.stream);
recorder.start();
recorder.ondataavailable = e => console.log("Got data", e.data);
recorder.onstop = () => console.log("stopped");
setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), 10000);
```

Comment: do you know how to do this in the native webrtc on iOS and Android?