# How to get remote audio stream in WebRTC on Android

Tags: android, webrtc

How can I get and convert the remote Audio stream data on Android? Preferably in the form of byte array buffers. I would then upload the data to some third party service to process.

I've seen something similar done on Web [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42138545/8170714) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51544362/8170714) with the help of [MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API), where they used `MediaRecorder` as the media to get the buffered data from `MediaStream` into an array. How can I do something similar on Android?

I know that it's possible to obtain the local audio data by setting a listener that implements `SamplesReadyCallback` in the `setSamplesReadyCallback()` method when creating the local `AudioDeviceModule` used for capturing local audio. This method doesn't really involve WebRTC's `PeerConnection`, it's essentially just setting a callback listener on the local audio data. Worst case scenario, I can just retrieve the local audio data by this method and send them off to the remote side via `DataChannel`, but I would still like a more ideal solution that can avoid sending essentially the same data twice.

Comment: what `MediaStream`? there is no such class in android SDK... what is your input data? is it PCM audio stream?

Comment: There is. You can get it from `PeerConnection.Observer`'s `onAddStream()` method.

Comment: I'm not trying to play it. I'm trying to get its buffered data as they become available, then convert them into byte array and send them to a third party service.

Comment: ah, sorry i missed `[webrtc]` tag...

Comment: @jackz314 Did you find the solution?

Comment: No. I ended up changing the code in the webrtc library and implement the feature myself because there are other features I needed not implemented in the original library

Comment: @jackz314 can you share some code snippets how you able to get remote AudioTrack bytes/buffer in android. It will help me to get a direction to start.

Comment: @Jack I also need this code snippets how to access raw audio of remote audio track

Comment: Which class did you modify?